# mac os x Component Object Model equivalent

Tags: macos, com, operating-system, openoffice.org

I'm trying to port an application I've written in Qt from the windows platform to the Mac OS X platform.

The application is relatively simple:
It queries the user for a document (either MS Word, or OOo Writer document). It than launches that that document inside the 
respective application, and than replaces various text elements with other data (Think Mailmerge).
It starts up the application and does the text replacing using QAxObject which is wrapper for COM.

Now I'm wanting to port this to the Mac OS X. I've installed Qt Creator on the Mac etc., but obivously COM is a windows technique not available on the Mac OS X.
So I've been looking around for techniques on the Mac OS X that are similiar to COM.

For now, I'm especially interested in using the OOo API http://api.openoffice.org/.

I'd like some pointers which techniques I should be looking at. I'm also willing to accept that this just plainly is not possible at all.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

A bit of information about COM on OS X is available in [this 2004 article](http://macdevcenter.com/pub/a/mac/2004/04/16/com_osx.html) from O'Reilly's MacDevCenter.

---

From the description of your problem, however, you're looking for something that works with Apple Events. Apple has developed an entire language for working with Apple Events, so most people equate them with the language -- AppleScript. You'll want to start exploring the field of scripting GUI applications with exploration of AppleScript, or Apple Events.

Each directly scriptable app has a "dictionary" of "verbs" and "nouns" you can manipulate. Nouns have properties, and name of the property is often either a string or the name of another noun (or a plural of a noun, which implies a collection - an array).

If the app doesn't have a dictionary (i.e. it isn't scriptable) or doesn't provide what you need via the dictionary, it is possible to send generic UI scripting commands to an "application" called "System Events".

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm -- not a lot of experience in the OOo arena, but have you considered using UNO, the component model that is part of OpenOffice?

Some documentation can be found in the Developer's Guide [here](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/FirstSteps/Programming_with_UNO).